# Error: ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate information gain in SQL. Below is my table:

`WORD, INSCALE NOTINSCALE D_FREQ
 book    22        19        41
 reserve 14        16        30`

The query is here:

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_2INFOGAIN (WORD, INFO_G) AS
SELECT WORD, 
-(17081/33676)*LOG(10,17081/33676)+(D_FREQ/33676)*(INSCALE/D_FREQ)*log(10, INSCALE/D_FREQ)+(NOTINSCALE/33676)*(NOTINSCALE/D_FREQ)*log(10, NOTINSCALE/D_FREQ) AS INFO_G
FROM FINAL_CONTIN2;
```

It keeps giving me this error:

> Error: ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range
>   01428. 00000 -  "argument '%s' is out of range"'.

The error points to 'D_FREQ' at `log(10, NOTINSCALE/D_FREQ)`.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: Are there other records besides the two you have specified in your table?

Answer (score 2):

With your example data, this works as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_2INFOGAIN (WORD, INFO_G) AS
WITH final_contin2(word, inscale, notinscale, d_freq) as (
  select 'book', 22, 19, 41 from dual 
  union all
  select 'reserve', 14, 16, 30 from dual
)
SELECT 
  WORD, 
  -(17081/33676)*LOG(10,17081/33676) +
    (D_FREQ/33676)*(INSCALE/D_FREQ)*log(10, INSCALE/D_FREQ) + 
    (NOTINSCALE/33676)*(NOTINSCALE/D_FREQ)*log(10, NOTINSCALE/D_FREQ) AS INFO_G
FROM FINAL_CONTIN2;
```

The error message you're getting is coming from the call to `log` - at least one of the rows in your *real* table FINAL_CONTIN2 contains values for inscale, notinscale and d_freq for which the expression `inscale/d_freq` resp. `notinscale/d_freq` becomes either 0 or negative.